# UTF - символы в регулярных выраженияж

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

в регулярных выражениях можно вставлять символы по их кодам вот так `\x20`

Но я не могу понять как там использовать четырёхзначные коды символов, например `\u2011`работает в простых строках, но не работает в регулярках.

Кто знает как в python без костылей писать 4-значные коды символов в регулярках?

Comment: Регулярные выражения бывают очень разные и не все вообще поддерживают юникод, о какой конкретно реализации речь?

Comment: в python3, модуль re

Comment: У него в принципе можно писать юникодные символы как есть вообще без всяких кодов (`re.search(r'[А-Яа-яЁё]+', 'строка')` отлично работает например), вам обязательно нужны именно коды?

Comment: `sub(r'([^-‑–]\d+)(?:\s+)', r'\1' + '\u00A0', text)`

Comment: я пробовал так, там 3 разных тире, но чёт не очень работает, работает как во втором параметре, но это костыль какой-то

Comment: Неразрывный пробел тоже легко записывается без кодов) И тире тоже

Comment: кодом как-то очевиднее что за символ, а то хрен поймёшь так что за символ обычный пробел или неразрывный

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75656/discussion-between---and-andreymal).

Comment: `print (re.sub(r'([^-‑–]\d+)\s+', "\\1\u00A0", text))` - пишите эти коды в обычных строковых литералах. А вы уверены, что регулярка у вас правильная? [`\b(?<![-‑–])(\d+)\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/X7yaht/1)?

Comment: А так вообще кириллические символы ломаются)

Comment: См. https://ideone.com/Z7uZlk, где что у вас сломано?

Comment: https://ideone.com/Ar9DuJ не то же самое, но похожий пример

Comment: Там у вас ошибка на ошибке. Смотрите мой пример, исправляйте, как там.

Comment: Да с двойным слешем нормально работает, с одним слешем похоже вставлялся какой-то неизвестный символ вместо вхождения, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r''` это не регулярное выражение, это raw string literal (вид строковых констант)—внутри таких констант `\X` заменяется на `\X` для любого X. То есть, если backslash не последний символ в константе, то он как-будто не имеет специального смысла (в отличии от обычных строковых констант `''`) и как есть вставляется.

Дополнительно, если константа используется чтобы задать регулярное выражение, то backslash дважды интерпретируется. К примеру, `'\1'` создаёт строку с одним Unicode символом U+0001. Если эту строку как регулярное выражение интерпретировать, то оно буквально совпадает с U+0001 символом:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('\1', '\u0001')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='\x01'>
```

Чтобы regex движок увидел backslash здесь, его необходимо экранировать в строке:

```
>>> '\\1' == r'\1'
True
>>> re.match('\\1', '\u0001')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference 1 at position 1
```

В этом случае константа создаёт строку из двух символов U+005C и U+0031, которые распознаются движком как ссылка на первую [несуществующую в примере] группу в regex.

Если вы напишите, `r'\u0061'`, то создаётся строка из 6 символов, что естественно отличается от `'\u0061'` (один символ).

Регулярное выражение можно задать как с помощью самого символа так и экранированной последовательности:

```
>>> re.match('\\u0061', 'a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
>>> re.match('\u0061', 'a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
```

Поэтому работают все варианты:

```
>>> re.match('[\u0060-\u0065]', 'a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
>>> re.match(r'[\u0060-\u0065]', 'a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
>>> re.match('[\\u0060-\\u0065]', 'a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
```

В подстановочной строке, `\u` последовательность не распознаётся regex движком, поэтому сам символ приходится использовать:

```
>>> re.sub('([\u0060-\u0065])', '\\1b', 'a a')
'ab ab'
>>> re.sub('([\u0060-\u0065])', '\\1\u0062', 'a a')
'ab ab'
>>> re.sub('([\u0060-\u0065])', '\\1\\u0062', 'a a')
'a\\u0062 a\\u0062'
>>> re.sub('([\u0060-\u0065])', r'\1' '\u0062', 'a a')
'ab ab'
```

Answer (score 2):

Данные коды можно использовать без проблем в обычных строковых литералах.

```
def link_conjunctions_with_words(text):
    return sub(r'\s+([\wА-Яа-я]{1,2})\s+', r' \1' + '\u00A0', text)
                                                    ^
```

Или

```
def link_conjunctions_with_words(text):
    return sub(r'\s+([\wА-Яа-я]{1,2})\s+', ' \\1\u00A0', text)
                                           ^
```

[См. испраленное демо](https://ideone.com/8hb4xx)

Следите за тем, как вы объявляете обратный слеш:

```
'\1' = 1 символ SOH (символ с кодом \x01)
'\\1' = r'\1' = 2 символа, \ и 1 (обратная ссылка в регулярках)
```

Comment: Но как использовать символ `\u2011` в самой регулярке и не путая с обычным тире

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду? Ещё раз: [`r'\u2011' != '\u2011'`](https://ideone.com/aM9p9u)

Comment: я имею в виду `re.match(r'' + '\u2011',text)`, но без костылей

Comment: @ЕвгенийТимофеев Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Найти в тексте все вхождения `\u2011`? Используйте `re.findall('\u2011', text)`. `re.match` находит одно совпадение и только в начале строки.

Comment: Нет, я хочу использовать этот символ в любых регулярных выражениях